# NestJS microservice not sending message via .send

Tags: nestjs, microservices, nestjs-microservice

I'm new to @nestjs/microservices, and running into a weird issue.

I have a setup of two apps written in Nest and checking the micro-service connection between them. For some strange reason, `clientProxy.emit / @EventPattern` works - but `clientProxy.send / @MessagePattern` is not. I've double checked the connection, it works fine. But the request/response approach does not work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..
Sending the request is as follows:

```
this.shortenerService
      .send('create', {
        url: 'test',
      });
```

[client code](https://github.com/akve/nest-ms-check/blob/main/apps/ac/src/ac.service.ts)

Receiving:

```
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @MessagePattern('create')
  async create(@Payload() data: CreateDto): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve(`${Math.random()}`);
  }
```

[server code](https://github.com/akve/nest-ms-check/blob/main/apps/url-shortener/src/url-shortener.controller.ts)

Tried to change to `.emit` in client and `@EventPattern` in server - and it works. But not for request/response.

Tried to organize into a [minimal repository](https://github.com/akve/nest-ms-check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest's microservice [`ClientProxy` uses observables, and `send`](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#sending-messages) are cold observables, so you need to either return the response of `.send` for Nest to later subscribe, use `.subscribe()` yourself to kick off the observable, or convert the observable to a promise using `lastValueFrom` so you can `await` the response

Comment: Thanks @jay-mcdoniel... Yes, the actual code is a bit different - but the call is not received by the 'server' (looking at the log), when it's request/response - but works fine with 'emit'

Comment: Right, because [as the docs mention](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#publishing-events) `.emit` is a "hot" observable, meaning it doesn't need to be subscribed to

Comment: Wow, thanks.. Due to optimization, even .toPromise() was not actually executed, needed to subscribe / use 'lastValueFrom' to get the call run. Thanks a lot!